# How to design a library which can serve a Haskell module over network?

Tags: haskell, template-haskell

The task here is as follows :

1. The client requests a function to be executed providing a name and it's arguments.
2. The server executes the function with the provided arguments and returns the result.

Something like this is fairly easy to implement in a dynamic typed language like Python. But, given Haskell's static typing, this seems increasingly difficult.

Here is my initial stab at the problem :

- Assume that the functions in the module only take arguments which are serializable. Implement a `Serializable` type class (idea taken from Cloud Haskell).
- Store the functions in a map keyed using the function name. Doesn't work. The values of the map (function objects) need not be of same type.
- The only thing I could come up with is to parse the module and generate a chain of `if else` statements (or a `case` statement) invoking the right function based on the input string and then serializing the result.

  This gives a pathetic performance as the worst case 'lookup' time of a function will be dependent on the number of functions in the module.

What is the right way to approach this problem? Is there something trivial that I'm missing here?

Comment: If the only thing that bothers about the last option is the linear time lookup, you can write/generate a number of functions of type `Bytes -> Bytes`, one for each function f, of shape `let (arg1, ..., argN) = deSerializeArgs input in serialize $ f arg1 ... argN`. Those functions can then be put into a map or whatever other structure you like. Of course, this is still quite some work and rather ugly.

Comment: Is there a problem with using cloud-haskell (aka distributed-process)?

Comment: You can use a `Map` for looking up the functions  - e.g. `Map String Handler` where `Handler` is something like `Bytes -> Bytes` or `FileHandle -> IO ()`. You'll just have a write a wrapper for each RPC  function.

Comment: One man's handy run-functions-over-the-network is another man's security black hole. Be sure the remotely run arbitrary code model is the best basis for your project before you use it as the foundation stone.

Comment: Haskell is the best dynamically typed language out there ;) Wrap your functions in a `Dynamic -> Dynamic` typed wrapper (from `Data.Dynamic`).

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution I could come up with. The idea is from @delnan/@user4502 coupled with the `Aeson` library.

Let's say I would like to 'serverize' a module `Foo`. A new module `Bar` will be generated where there are wrappers for the functions in module `Foo`.

For example, if a function `splitAt` in module `Foo` has the type signature :

```
    splitAt :: Int -> [Int] -> ([Int], [Int])
```

The corresponding wrapper function `_splitAt` in `Bar` will have the type signature :

```
    _splitAt :: ByteString -> ByteString
```

The generated `Bar` module will be something like this :

```
    module Bar where

    import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as L
    import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as LC
    import qualified Foo as F
    import qualified Data.Aeson as DA

    errMsg = LC.pack "Invalid Input"

    _splitAt :: L.ByteString->L.ByteString
    _splitAt input = let args = DA.decode input :: Maybe (Int, [Int])
                     in case args of 
                       (Just (arg1, arg2)) -> DA.encode $ F.splitAt arg1 arg2
                       Nothing -> errMsg

    -- And the rest of the functions
```

Now, since all functions are of the type `ByteString -> ByteString`, they can be placed in a `Map`.

This works but, can the code of `_splitAt` be refactored to avoid the type suggestion (not sure of the terminology) `Maybe (Int, [Int])`?

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume that all our functions work within some common monad `M`, which I guess will be a common case (to handle errors etc.). So our functions will have types like `f :: a -> b -> c -> M d`.

The idea is to convert all functions into one common type. Let's say we're using [aeson](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson). Then the common type we're seeking is

```
type RPC m = forall i o . (FromJSON i, ToJSON o) => i -> m o
```

(using [RankNTypes](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.3/html/users_guide/other-type-extensions.html#universal-quantification)).

We can proceed as follows:

- Given a function name, use TH's [reify](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/template-haskell-2.8.0.0/docs/Language-Haskell-TH-Syntax.html#v%3areify) to inspect its type.
- Enumerate how many arguments a function has and apply the corresponding [uncurrying](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Currying) function. For example, our example above has 3 arguments so it'd be converted into

  ```
  uncurry3 f :: (a, b, c) -> M d
  ```

  where `uncurry3` can be easily generated automatically using TH (perhaps there is a package for it). Don't forget to convert functions of type `M a` into `() -> M a`.
- Now all functions fit into `RPC M`, so we can create a `Map String (RPC M)` from a list of functions (`reify` also gives us function names). For example something like `mkRPC :: [Name] -> Q Exp`.
- Finally, we create a handler that takes `Map String (RPC M)`, a user request and processes it, calling the appropriate function from the map.

The client side would be very similar.

Comment: I'm wondering if you would prefer TH over a type class approach -- e.g.  [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21362498/applying-a-list-of-strings-to-an-arbitrary-function). Thanks!

Comment: @user5402 I've been already using TH in the project, so it was a natural choice. A type-class approach would be nice, but I'm afraid it's not possible to avoid `UndecidableInstances` or `OverlappingInstances`, which usually makes the result useless. The general problem is that if you have a 1-argument function `a -> b`, you can specialize `b` to `c -> d` and suddenly you have a 2-argument function `a -> c - > d`.