# applying a list of Strings to an arbitrary function

Tags: haskell, ghc, type-families

I'm trying to write a function which allows you to "apply" a list of Strings to an arbitrary function. Here's what I've got so far:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses, FlexibleInstances, OverlappingInstances, TypeFamilies #-}

class Apply a c
  where apply :: a -> [String] -> c

instance (Read a, Apply b c) => Apply (a -> b) c
  where apply _ [] = error "not enough arguments"
        apply f (x:xs) = apply (f (read x)) xs

instance (a ~ b) => Apply a b 
  where apply f [] = f
        apply _ (_:_) = error "too many arguments"
```

Examples:

```
g1 :: Int -> Bool
g1 x = x > 10

g2 :: Bool -> Int -> Int
g2 b n = if b then 10*n else n-1

test1 = apply g1 ["3"]              -- False
test2 = apply g2 ["True", "33"]     -- 330
test3 = apply g2 ["False", "0"]     -- -1
test4 = apply g2 []                 -- error "not enough arguments"
test5 = apply g2 ["True", "3", "x"] -- error "too many arguments"
test6 = apply (length :: [Int] -> Int) ["[4,5,6]"]           -- 3
test7 = apply (tail :: [Char] -> [Char]) [ "['a','b','c']" ] -- "bc"
```

I'd like to write something like the following:

```
wrap :: (Show b, Apply a b) => a -> ([String] -> String)
wrap f xs = show $ apply f xs
```

but GHC complains with: `Could not deduce (Show a0) arising from a use of 'show' ...`

However, specific definitions work:

```
w1 xs = show $ apply g1 xs
w2 xs = show $ apply g2 xs
```

and result in functions of type `[String] -> String`:

```
test8 = w1 ["20"]          -- "True"
test9 = w2 ["False", "3" ] -- "2"
```

Is there a way I can get `wrap` to work? Is there a better way to implement `apply`?

Answer (score 4):

You can also try changing the declaration of Apply to

```
class Apply a c | a -> c
     where apply :: a -> [String] -> c
```

And adding the FunctionalDependencies extension, your current wrap signature works

I believe this is all related to the Overlapping Instances error that you get after the "Could not deduce" error.

Comment: This seems like a good idea anyway as it removes the ambiguity over what the "result" of a curried function is.

Comment: Did you also have to add `LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances`?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to work if you add `ScopedTypeVariables` and write this:

```
wrap :: forall a b . (Show b, Apply a b) => a -> ([String] -> String)
wrap f xs = show (apply f xs :: b)
```

To be honest I'm not quite sure why this fixes it, but you're in delicate territory with the two overlapping instances for `Apply` and I think this was needed to persuade GHC to use the passed in `Apply` instance declared in the type signature of `wrap` instead of resolving the call to `apply` immediately with the `a ~ b` instance and then wanting `Show` for the type of `f` as a consequence.